# zf2 socket http adapter not working

Tags: sockets, rss, zend-framework2

I am trying to consume a rss feed and, on SO, I found the following code:

```php
try {

    $rss = Reader::import('http://www.wdcdn.net/rss/presentation/library/client/skunkus/id/cc3d06c1cc3834464aef22836c55d13a');
} catch (Exception\RuntimeException $e) {
    echo "error : " . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$channel = array(
    'title' => $rss->getTitle(),
    'description' => $rss->getDescription(),
    'link' => $rss->getLink(),
    'items' => array()
);

foreach ($rss as $item) {
    $channel['items'][] = array(
        'title' => $item->getTitle(),
        'link' => $item->getLink(),
        'description' => $item->getDescription(),
        // 'image'       => $item->getImage(),
    );
}

return new  ViewModel(array(
    'channel' => $channel
));
```

When I try to run the code, I get the following error

```
Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException

Fichier:
C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket.php:258
Message:
Unable to connect to www.wdcdn.net:80 . Error #0: stream_socket_client(): 
Pile d'exécution:
#0 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Http\Client.php(1358): Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket->connect('www.wdcdn.net', 80, false)
#1 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Http\Client.php(878): Zend\Http\Client->doRequest(Object(Zend\Uri\Http), 'GET', false, Array, '')
#2 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader.php(249): Zend\Http\Client->send()
#3 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\IndexController.php(60): Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader::import('http://www.wdcd...')
#4 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Application\Controller\IndexController->homeAction()
#5 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#6 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#8 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#9 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#10 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(316): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#14 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\public\index.php(12): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#15 {main}
Exceptions précédentes:

ErrorException

Fichier:
C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket.php:253
Message:
stream_socket_client(): 
Pile d'exécution:
#0 [internal function]: Zend\Stdlib\ErrorHandler::addError(2, 'stream_socket_c...', 'C:\Workspace\df...', 253, Array)
#1 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket.php(253): stream_socket_client('www.wdcdn.net:8...', 10061, 'Aucune connexio...', 10, 4, Resource id #207)
#2 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Http\Client.php(1358): Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket->connect('www.wdcdn.net', 80, false)
#3 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Http\Client.php(878): Zend\Http\Client->doRequest(Object(Zend\Uri\Http), 'GET', false, Array, '')
#4 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader.php(249): Zend\Http\Client->send()
#5 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\IndexController.php(60): Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader::import('http://www.wdcd...')
#6 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Application\Controller\IndexController->homeAction()
#7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#12 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#15 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(316): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 C:\Workspace\app\intranet\public\index.php(12): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#17 {main}
```

I've tried to dig into Zend code, and if I change the default ZendHttp\Client to cURL, everythings works well.

My question is, why the socket raise an error **#0** (from php.net: *If the value returned in errno is 0 and the function returned FALSE, it is an indication that the error occurred before the connect() call.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend's [Feed Reader](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.feed.reader.html) has a static `setClient()` method and this method works with any http client which has an adapter that implements [AdapterInterface](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/AdapterInterface.php).

So you can easily try something like this:

```
$config = array(
   'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
   );

$client = new HttpClient(null, $config);
Reader::setHttpClient($client);
$feed = Reader::import('http://www.wdcdn.net/rss/presentation/library/client/skunkus/id/cc3d06c1cc3834464aef22836c55d13a');
```

Don't forget to add the lines below after your namespace declaration:

```
use Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader;
use Zend\Http\Client as HttpClient;
```

It should work since you don't have any network problem.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've done, but I wanted to know why the socket errors occurs, is it possible that it comes from some network configurations ? (NAT, proxy etc)

Comment: You are dealing with a connection problem. What happening when you call same feed url in your browser? After your comment i also tried to run the sample code in my answer and it worked.

Comment: it works if I call it in browser, and it works too using a cUrl adapter instead of socket one, so I guess it's my network configuration fault